# Do particles with higher spins have shorter wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, history, spin-models

When they say that a half-spin particle 'spins' through 720° before returning to its original state, does that mean it has travelled twice as far as an otherwise identical particle possessing the same mass, velocity, etc. but with a spin of one?

Spin still confuses me....

Comment: The de Broglie relation $\lambda=h/p$ does not involve spin.